# uwsgi emperor share and use a common default ini within projects

Tags: flask, uwsgi, ini

I'm using the uwsgi Emperor to manage multiple Flask apps, and for each individual app, I have several ini configs, e.g. `local.ini`, `production.ini` that I want to share common ini features from a central `default.ini`.  And I'd like be able to do this for multiple projects, i.e. different projects can have different defaults.  However, I cannot get the emperor to follow the symlinks to recognize the `default.ini` file.  How do I get the emperor to follow symlinks so each project can understand its default.ini location?  I always get the error
`realpath() of default.ini failed: No such file or directory`

`emperor.ini` setup file

```
[uwsgi]
emperor = /www/uwsgi/vassals
emperor-broodlord = 40
logto = /www/uwsgi/log/emperor.log
master = true
thunder-lock = true
enable-threads = true
stats = /tmp/empstats.sock
die-on-term = true
```

My vassals directory is set up with symlinks that point to the respective projects ini files

```
uwsgi_app1.ini -> /path/to/project1/local.ini 
uwsgi_app2.ini -> /path/to/project2/local.ini
```

For each separate project, I have a `default.ini` which contains common settings I want to use for both local and production environments, for that project.

Project1
`default.ini`

```
[uwsgi]

file = %(wwwdir)/%(module)/run_%(app_name)
daemonize = %(wwwdir)/%(module)/log/%(app_name).log
socket = %(socketdir)/uwsgi_%(app_name).sock
stats = %(socketdir)/%(module)_stats.sock

master = true
processes = 4

chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
thunder-lock = true
enable-threads = true
lazy-apps = true
```

with `local.ini` and `production.ini`, having slightly different variables, being

local

```
[uwsgi]
callable = app
wwwdir = /localwww/
socketdir = /tmp
module = app1
app_name = app1
ini = default.ini
```

production

```
[uwsgi]
callable = app
wwwdir = /home/var-www/
socketdir = /run/uwsgi/tmp
module = app1
app_name = app1
ini = default.ini
```

If I use the `%p` magic variable to specify the absolute path, it instead points to the emperor vassal directory `www/uwsgi/vassals/default.ini`, rather than the real path.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a full path to the default.ini in the project file...

ini = /path/to/my/project/config/uwsgi/defaults.ini